# Role of repetition in Central Limit Theory

Tags: central-limit-theorem

What is the role of repetitions in Central Limit theory?
If anyone can explain, intuitively and mathematically.
Please refer to the image where one sampling distribution is with 5 reps and another one is with 10K

Std error of mean doesnt get affected i guess since SE = SD/sqrt(n) where n is sample size.
Everywhere it is mentioned that n should be large enough.

[Sampling repetition and distribution of means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQFeQ.png)

the pic is generated using http://onlinestatbook.com/stat_sim/sampling_dist/

Comment: The importance of the central limit theorem is that the distribution does not matter, if the sample size tends to $\infty$ (in practice, if it is "large enough", the error is "small"). In plain text the theorem can be formulated as follows : If a random variable is the sum of many independent summands each contributing only a little to the sum, then the variable is approximately normal distributed.

Comment: you mean to say, if sample is large enough, repetitions doesnt matter much? Would be great if you can through some light on role of repetitions

Comment: The repetitions are crucial. The outcome of the first sample is the random variable $X_1$ , the outcome of the second $X_2$ and so on upto $X_n$. If the $X_i$ are equally distributed and independent (the distribution of $X_1$ does not matter) and $n$ is "large", the sum (and therefore also the mean) is approximately normal distributed. This is the content of the Central limit theorem.

Comment: For an example, we want to know average height of people of a school (N=1500), we take a large enough sample for e.g. 150 and measure their height. This is how samples are taken in practice. Is CLT applicable here? Confidence interval calculation is applicable?